# How in-app billing v3 works ? and what is the secured way to implement it?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I want implement the in-app billing v3. I have gone through  [google developers site](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html)
understood how purchase works but my questions are

- What are the challenges in implementing secured in app billing.
- How to do server side signature verification ?

any other in-app billing related information will be helfull.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: too many broad questions...voting to close

Comment: @Leo Sorry i have modified the question. Mainly i am worried about security.